# Development and Production Branches

Tags: git, merge, branch

I am looking for a workflow where I have a Development Branch where I push my daily development work. Then  have a Production Branch which I want to contain the latest development at the end of the the week.  I do not want this branch to contain all of the commits from the past weeks development work, just the code at the end of the week.

I have tried merging, but this merges all the previous commits on the development branch on to the production branch..

Is there a method of doing what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)?

The main idea is that you have a development branch for current development and master branch for releases (consistent with production).

I think the "end of the week" principle goes hand-in-hand with "release branches." Release branches would be called something like `origin/git-repo/release-v3` or in your case `origin/git-repo/release-2020-11-06`.

At the end of the week you would merge develop branch with this release branch.

---

Unfortunately all the commits will still be in the release branch, and when you merge release with master, all the commits will be in master branch as well. However, this is normal procedure. It's normal for the production branch to have all the previous commits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve with your workflow, generally you would like to keep the history in your `master` branch. So I would suggest following the gitflow in the previous post.

However, if you still want to follow through, one thing you could do is:

```
git checkout master
```

then

```
git merge --squash develop
```

or whatever you are calling the branch you would like to merge. The simply do

```
git commit
```

and you will have all your previous commits squashed into one and committed to your master branch.

**Note:** You will not get a proper merge commit from this, so your history might look a bit strange.